# How is this POB?

Tags: discussion

My question [Why would a colony need to relocate?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69665/why-would-a-colony-need-to-relocate) got a lot of flak along the lines of “what would determine which answer is best?”

But how is this different from any other question, like

[What kind of apocalypse could reset the world to middle age technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69688/what-kind-of-apocalypse-could-reset-the-world-to-middle-age-technology)

[What would a civilization living in a cold, permanently snowy climate eat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69546/what-would-a-civilization-living-in-a-cold-permanently-snowy-climate-eat)

[Reasons a future branch of Islam would be against AI?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69549/reasons-a-future-branch-of-islam-would-be-against-ai)

[How could immortal children age faster than immortal adults?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69564/how-could-immortal-children-age-faster-than-immortal-adults)

Just reading off the current front page.  What about my post says anything about needing a “best” reason, as the comments insist?

Really— tell me what I’m missing so I can fix the question.  I honestly see nothing different in nature compared with all the “**reasons**”, “**what**”, or “**how**” questions here.

I find these to be the most interesting to read, looking at all the different creative takes on it (and perhaps adding my own).

This question is also well received with a good number of upvotes and answers in the time it was open.

Comment: You raise some valid points but I have to disagree with your last one: some of the most upvoted, answered questions are still not fit for site standards. [See here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18051/tomorrow-is-groundhog-day-for-everyone-how-does-society-respond).

Comment: I think we can expand on this to make a larger discussion - there are definitely inconsistencies with how questions are assessed on here. We should define site standards a bit more clearly, and perhaps a separate or followup question could touch on this idea.

Comment: @Zxyrra Definitely there are inconsistencies about assessing questions. Standards need to be clearer. Too often I've seen questions assessed in ways that do not make sense. Reasons for closure, putting on hold, downvoting and upvoting at times seem to be applied erratically and inconsistently. Any followup would be appreciated.

Comment: @Zxyrra some? each one(maybe there are exceptions ), ok 90% (my opinion)

Comment: @Zxyrra define, first you have to understand what your standards actually are. To understand and accept the WB is different than some SE sites. And if you jump right into writing and defining new standards without understanding the current situation better, nothing good is expected.

Answer (score 4):

### You've made a good point

While there are several reasons to close a question as opinion-based, they are not applied consistently, and you have evidenced that clearly. I will retract my close vote so you can get answers, and after we have clear guidelines, we will decide if a close vote is appropriate.

EDIT: [Discussion can be found here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/redefining-what-we-want-to-close).

Comment: Always good to see someone who is prepared to change his mind. It takes more strength of character to do than most people realize. This gets my vote of approval. I will look forward to clearer guidelines.

Comment: Looks like it needs to gather votes for reopening.

Comment: @JDługosz See the linked discussion.